# strange behaviour safe parameter in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

When I'm not using safe parameter in model's rules,  I got the message [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "id" of "Comment".

but in my php, I can check the id of a new comment

```
.....
if ($model->save()) {
      $comment_id = $model->id; -- value of the new comment_id OK
}
.....
```

if I put the statement

```
array('id', 'safe'),
```

in the comment model.

I dont get the error Failed to set unsafe   anymore  but  comment_id   is equal to NULL in my php code

Is anyone have an explanation?

Comment: there is no any error, can you show more code?

Comment: Are you assigning the primary ID yourself? If it's an auto increment you shouldn't have to add that validation rule. In any: What Alex says is correct. You are not giving a lot of information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: $comment_id is a local variable, you need to do something like $commentModel = Comment::model(...), and then $commentModel->id = $model->id